# clientStream.Read returns wrong number of bytes

Tags: c#, networking

This code works:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
byte[] message = new byte[5242880];
int bytesRead;

bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 909699);
```

But this returns the wrong number of bytes:

```
bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 5242880);
```

Why? How can I fix it?

(the real data size is 1475186; the code returns the 11043 as the number of bytes)

Comment: What does it mean when you say "doesn't work"?

Comment: And every time it returns a new number for the number of bytes

Comment: Maybe the data isn't sent at once, but rather divided into packets. And those 11043 is the size of the first packet. So you probably have to create a loop around the `Read`.

Comment: The number of bytes is wrong,it's not reading the whole chunk of data.

Comment: What's the type of all these variables? And how did you create the instances? Please show more code.

Comment: I know,I want the whole chunk at the same time.

Comment: I am not sure what type of stream it is, but I would steer clear of defining the number of bytes you expect to receive. Isnt there a ReadToEnd or similar function?

Comment: While the description is incomplete, I guess that it's the usual problem with TCP, where people don't realize it's stream and not message based.

Comment: 5242880 bytes is 5 MB that will probably not arrive in a single block.

Comment: Likewise...909699 bytes is less then 1MB which might arrive in a single block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is a TCP based stream, then the answer is that the rest of the data simply didn't arrive yet.

TCP is stream oriented. That means there is no relation between the number of `Send`/`Write` calls, and the number of receive events. Multiple writes can be combined together, and single writes can be split.

If you want to work with messages on TCP, you need to implement your own packeting algorithm on top of it. Typical strategies to achieve this are:

1. Prefix each packed by its length, usual with binary data
2. Use a separation sequence such as a line-break. Usual with text data.

---

If you want to read all data in a blocking way you can use loop until `DataAvailable` is `true` but a subsequent call to `Read` returns `0`. (Hope I remembered that part correctly, haven't done any network programming in a while)

Comment: Example to get all data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx

Comment: @duedl0r 1) You posted a link to the auto translated German version of MSDN. 2) Are you sure that example reads to the end? I think it only reads all available data, and thus ends if part of the data hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: 1) uh sry about that. 2) yes it only reads available data. you can't expect more, you have to implement a packeting algorithm as you described. I just thought you could complement your answer with the link.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the
>   number of bytes specified by the size parameter.

I.e. you have to call the Read() method in a loop until you received all data. Have a look at the [sample code in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop reading bytes from the message until the [Available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available.aspx) property on the TCP client or the [DataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) property of the NetworkStream are 0 (= no more bytes left)

Comment: `DataAvailable` is a bool and thus can't be 0. If I recall correctly the correct pattern to read to the end is checking for `DataAvailable==true` but `Read` returning `0` afterwards.

Comment: @CodeInChaos True, DataAvailable is a bool. I've always used the Available property on the TCP clientwith no problems (so far!) though.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx):

> This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the
>   number of bytes successfully read. If no data is available for
>   reading, the Read method returns 0. The Read operation reads as much
>   data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size
>   parameter. If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all
>   available data has been received, the Read method completes
>   immediately and return zero bytes.

So it could be because of connection failure that you get each time different number, anyway you can check the result to know if its the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers already here respond to your specific question quite well, but possibly more generally: If you are trying to send data over a networkStream object for the purposes of network communication check out the open source library, [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/).